# Android gallery scrolling issue

Tags: android, caching, imageview, android-ion

When image gallery is wider than screen and I scroll it - images is re-loading all the time.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
.....
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, parent, false);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivGalleryItem);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        } 
         ....
         Ion.with(context)
            .load(holder.imagePath)
            .withBitmap()
            .intoImageView(imageView);  
    }
 }
```

I asume Ion is caching image by default but gallery still hide and show it during scrolling.

So, where is my problem an d how to fix?

Comment: Mind including a video of the issue? Post to youtube or something (author of ion here)

Comment: Also, for brevity, you could do Ion.with(imageView).load(imagePath)

Comment: Video is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6eamNwFF7j9dlVIUnpZWGVQTzg/view

Comment: How big are those images? If they're really big, they may just be getting knocked out of the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend not creating an imageview in every getView. Reuse your convertView if not null. There may be some recycling issues happening here.

Comment: I've changed as suggested. Did not help.